Trying to rig a multi-object character, why is parenting resulting in weird transforms?
I sculpted a model I'm fairly happy with in Zbrush, and am trying to get it into animatable form in Blender.
I sculpted the model using about 20 different subtools, because I wanted to use different materials for each.
Exported to FBX, and imported into Blender.  So far so good.
Other than decimation (it was 6M polygons at one point), I have made no changes to the mesh in Blender.
The character is made up of multiple separate objects, so I need to rig them all to the same armature.
I tried parenting the separate objects to one another, but whenever I do this every child object becomes gigantic, larger than the whole editing window, and turn sideways.  I think some of them are inside-out.
I also tried ctrl-J joining all the meshes into a single thing, but whenever I try to parent it to an armature it does the same thing.  Turns gigantic and flips over.
I'd PREFER that the individual accessory objects remain individual, rather than being a conjoined mesh.
I am parenting both by shift-dragging child objects onto parent in the window, and also by control-P in the editing area.

I've spent three weeks trying to crack this and watched at least 200 tutorials.
Blend file via Google Drive

Someone somewhere said something about checking the scale and origin of the objects.  I checked all this.  At least I think I did.  All are scaled 1:1 and origin is set to geometry.

Something got a weird scale, and you could try to select all A and apply scale (ctrl+a). When you parent, make sure you use "keep transform"

Selected all with A, hit ctrl-A and selected Scale.  Nothing appears to have happened.

Is there anything I can do to correct a weird scale?  What might have caused this?

This must be done "before" things change size weirdly.

Share the file in your question (before the problem occurs): https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Are you sure the armature is at zero rotation and location, and 1,1,1 scale?

@TheLabCat the armature isn't being parented in this case.  This is what happens when I try to parent the sub-meshes to the main mesh.  In any case, as noted above I believe I verified that the scale is 1:1

@DanielMöller too large for BlendExchange, but here it is on Google Drive.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/18ugxRpM3BueMm5LIQa7wQPkGIK7Phg0U/view?usp=sharing

ALL the accessory objects have 0.004 scale, and 90 degree X rotation, and are already parented to the skin object. Changing their parenting hierarchy when they have transforms will naturally screw things up. As Daniel suggested, select all, then use 3D Viewport header -> Object menu -> Apply -> Rotation & Scale. After that, you should be able to Parent (Keep Transform) the objects to eachother as you please.

Thank you I will try that.  Why are my objects at 0.004 scale?  Is it because of zBrush?  Where do you see that?  How do I prevent that happening in the future?

Also is parenting to the "skin" object wrong?  That's the name of the main object that all the others attach to.

I would generally parent any deforming object directly to the armature. It is what deforms them, so it should be in charge of transforming them too. As for the odd transforms, why ZBrush did it that way is unfortunately out of scope for me and this site.

During the procedure of binding some meshes to an armature with Ctrl P, every mesh object gets parented to the armature object: if the mesh was parented to some other object, this parenting gets canceled; if the parent had some transform values others than 000 000 111, this transformations gets cancelled, creating this "jump" in loc, rot and scale.
To have an "Hassle free" binding, this is the complete procedure you should use:
select a piece of mesh, one by one, press Alt P > Unparent (keep transform), then Ctrl A > Apply all transform, then H to temporarily hide the mesh.
Repeat for every piece.
Alt H to un hide.
Keep your N properties panel open if you want to read the values that are changing with this operation, and the object properties panel to check the parenting, that at the end of the rigging process will become: everything parented to the armature.
When you will be confident with this procedure, you will hold Alt key to confirm theese operations on multiple objects selected, without the need to do them one by one.


I understand.  thank you all very much.
